# RabbitMQ consuming messages from queue by the priority

Tags: php, rabbitmq

The idea is that I want to receive messages like 'link 123456', 'code 1234'.

Link number must be consumed as fast as it is possible, while code can wait while all current link numbers are consumed.RabbitMQ documentation from here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html is pretty short and clean, but does not help me at all.
When i follow it, messages completely ignore priority and are shown in order in which they were sent.

I tried to implement it in Java as it was shown in the example, but the outcome was the same.

Code of senders:

sender with priority 5

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection;
use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;
use PhpAmqpLib\Wire\AMQPTable;

$connection = new AMQPStreamConnection('localhost', 5672, 'guest', 'guest');
$channel = $connection->channel();
$table = [
    'maxPriority' => ['I', 10],
];
$channel->queue_declare('queue', false, true, false, false, false, $table);

$msg = new AMQPMessage('link: '.$_SERVER['argv'][1], [
                                              'delivery_mode' => 2,
                                              'priority' => 5,
                                            ]);
$channel->basic_publish($msg, '', 'queue');
$channel->close();
$connection->close();
?>
```

sender with priority 1

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection;
use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;
use PhpAmqpLib\Wire\AMQPTable;

$connection = new AMQPStreamConnection('localhost', 5672, 'guest', 'guest');
$channel = $connection->channel();
$table = [
    'maxPriority' => ['I', 10],
];
$channel->queue_declare('queue', false, true, false, false, false, $table);

$msg = new AMQPMessage('code: '.$_SERVER['argv'][1], [
                                              'delivery_mode' => 2,
                                              'priority' => 1,
                                            ]);
$channel->basic_publish($msg, '', 'queue');
$channel->close();
$connection->close();
?>
```

Code of receiver:

```
<?php
    require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection;
    use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;
    use PhpAmqpLib\Wire\AMQPTable;
    function s($str, $charset = null) {
        return new \Delight\Str\Str($str, $charset);
    }
    $connection = new AMQPStreamConnection('localhost', 5672, 'guest', 'guest');
    $channel = $connection->channel();
    $table = [
        'maxPriority' => ['I', 10],
    ];
    $channel->queue_declare('queue', false, true, false, false, false, $table);
    echo ' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C', "\n";
    $callback = function($msg){
        file_put_contents('rabbit_logs.txt', $msg->body."\r\n", FILE_APPEND);
        if( (new \Delight\Str\Str($msg->body))->startsWith('code: ')==1){
            echo " [x] Received ", $msg->body, "\n";
            sleep(1);
            echo " [x] Code sent", "\n";
        }
        else{
            if( (new \Delight\Str\Str($msg->body))->startsWith('lead: ')==1){
                echo " [x] Received ", $msg->body, "\n";
                sleep(1);
                echo " [x] lead sent", "\n";
            }
            else{
                if( (new \Delight\Str\Str($msg->body))->startsWith('link: ')==1){
                    echo " [x] Received ", $msg->body, "\n";
                    sleep(1);
                    echo " [x] link sent", "\n";
                }
                else{
                    echo " [x] Received ", $msg->body, "\n";      
                    echo " [x] Nothing sent", "\n";
                }
            }
        }
        $msg->delivery_info['channel']->basic_ack($msg->delivery_info['delivery_tag']);
    };
    $channel->basic_qos(null, 1, null);
    $channel->basic_consume('queue', '', false, false, false, false, $callback);
    while(count($channel->callbacks)) {
        $channel->wait();
    }
    $channel->close();
    $connection->close();
?>
```

Comment: I have very little knowledge about rabbitmq. As per my knowledge Receiver receive the msgs send by the sender in sequence (one by one), but you may find something from here https://groups.google.com/forum/?nomobile=true#!forum/rabbitmq-users

Comment: The documentation seems to be using `x-max-priority` as the setting for the max priority for the queue, your passing `maxPriority`

Comment: When I use x-max-priority it won't even run. Google told me that it was so when it was a plugin, but now it is in the core and renamed to maxPriority.
https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node/issues/165
Here in the bottom

Comment: Can you indicate whether you have pushed a few messages first, then started the consumer, or you had the consumer started right away? Reason of the question is that the [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html) indicates that if the messages are picked up too fast, there is no time for the queue to prioritize them

Comment: I tried both methods. I understand that sometimes messages cannot be prioritized, but even if i start receive script after pushing hundred of messages, in terminal I see them in order in which they were sent.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `x-max-priority` argument and build the argument table as shown in [this demo](https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/blob/master/demo/queue_arguments.php#L17-L21).